# How to manage a large number of external servers mount paths?

Tags: finder, mount

During my typical workflow I need to connect to 10 to 15 different servers (samba and ftp), depending on the work I am doing. Usually I press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> in the Finder and select one of them in my Favorites list. Some of the servers I also placed in the sidebar's Favorites to connect to them quicker. However, this is also awkward as the list in my sidebar is already rather long and some servers have the same name, which cannot be changed there.

Can you recommend a better workflow or a tool when working with a large number of servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create aliases and put those anywhere. In Finder, navigate to a shared folder or any path inside, then create an alias. You can create an alias by ⇧⌘-dragging a folder.

You can place this alias anywhere in any hierarchy, such as a folder in your documents, and when opening the alias, Finder will resolve the alias and connect to the relevant server.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I created the folder 'servers' in my home folder and placed it into the dock. Now I can quickly access it and also rename the shortcuts.